# Nicest way to map RGB colors from HTML to LED

Tags: html, color

I have attached a RGB LED to a color picker on a webpage and have hit the obvious problem that though the LED takes 8-bit values (like HTML) the color rendering is very different so with the more subtle shades the LED values for the color are wildly different to the HTML values.

The brute-force method would be for me to have a lookup-table on the webserver to map the two sets of values but would ideally like to do it more elegantly.

Before I start listing all my 101 ideas for doing this I wondered if anyone else had come across the issue, the end-game would be to be able to abstract the color-rendering of different LEDs and make it available as a webservice (HTML value and device id in, LED value out).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a table to store the mapping, consider building a "curve" for it: a mathematical function to calculate the conversions.  There are infinitely many ways to do this, but you can probably pick something simple like Béziers or polynomials.  The curve will have some unknown parameters that you'll need to fiddle with in order to produce the right results ("calibration").

For example, a really simple curve would be:

```
R = r ^ a
```

where `r` is the original red component (scaled to the range from 0 to 1) and `R` is the new red component (scaled to the same range from 0 to 1).  The number `a` is a parameter that can be used for calibration (can range from 0 to ∞).

Note that HTML colors are 24-bits, whereas your LEDs are 8-bits, so you will need to do some downsampling.  Doing this just adds a minor complication to the conversion formula earlier.  You'll need to figure out the palette used by the 8-bit system, and round your values to those colors (no lookup tables are necessary unless the palette is really whacky).

Comment: I saw an artical about doing the transition within HSI colorspace to create the curve, what do you think? http://blog.saikoled.com/post/43693602826/why-every-led-light-should-be-using-hsi-colorspace

Comment: I don't think that's directly relevant as it's talking about HSI to RGB conversions.

Comment: Following something someone else said, I've started reading up on ICC profiles which seems to cover both lookup tables and algorithmic matching, seems overkill for my purpose but maybe I can  come up with an ICC-lite! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're trying to map 24-bit colors to 8-bit outputs (or inputs for your LED), where your color ranges are a lot more reduced - and probably provide only a segment of the actual code to your LED. To understand this better, please read [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors) and pay particular attention to "web-safe colors", because ultimately this is what you need to provide to your LED driver.

To actually provide your user with a realistic option, you could try and use [this 8-bit color picker](http://bilalq.github.io/eight-bit-color-picker) or a similar one you feel comfortable with, or even implement your own, and see if that does the trick.

Comment: HTML colors without alpha are *24-bit*, with 8 bits per channel.

Comment: The other issue is that the LED won't have the same [gamut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut) as the display.

Comment: Thank you both for the input! @Rufflewind, I corrected my answer (need to be more focused when I'm writing - sorry for that one)! Blrfl, I didn't work with RGB LEDs until now, I assumed he's using some driver to render the RGB values onto the LED inputs properly.

Comment: The way I am doing it is to use a light that uses the high-level "DMX" protocol (which is de-facto in theatre and concert lighting) so its the lamps inbuilt driver that is converting my values to physical control.

Answer (score 0):

This would be impossible to do directly, because it depends heavily on calibration of the display and what kind of LED you are using. And also from different way human eye sees colors.

One way I think would be possible to provide your own "calibration". Display to the user multiple questions where each question will activate one color on LED and display multiple colors. Then have user pick the color, which is closes to the LED. Then you will have some data from which you can build calibration curve/table. It would also be good idea to make new questions based on previous calibration, so user will converge to calibration, that will represent his display.

Comment: That was one of the ways I was thinking of building my "brute-force" table. Show a "key" or "difficult" colors based on a guess by the db, if not "good enough", have the user match it, the db could then adjust the "guesses" in the table based on it and repeat until the guesses are marked "good enough" by user. This still leaves me to create the "guess" algorhytm